# R shiny datatables don't show records (rows) at start

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I am building a shiny app with datatables. 
What I want is that there are no records (rows) shown on startup. So that you only see the filters at the top of the table. When you start typing the rows are shown. 
I can't find an option in Datatables. Is this possible?

An example code is here below.

```
    shinyApp(

ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'DataTable',
    DT::dataTableOutput('ex2')
),

server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(
            iris, 
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All'))
            )
        )
    )

}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your own search functionality:

EDIT: added second `character` column that is being searched.

```
shinyApp(

  ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'DataTable',
    textInput('search', 'search'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('ex2')
  ),


  server = function(input, output, session) {

    require(dplyr)
    iris.mut <- iris %>% 
      mutate(bottom = paste0('v',sapply(Sepal.Width,function(x)paste0(rep('z',x*2),collapse="")),'bx'))

    dat <- reactive({

      if(input$search!=''){
        iris.mut %>%
          filter(grepl(input$search,Species)|grepl(input$search,bottom))
      } else {
        iris.mut %>%
          filter(Species == input$search)
      }
    })

    output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(
        dat(), 
        options = list(
          lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All'))
        )
      ))

  }
)
```

Comment: This is useful. However, how can you do this for multiple columns. First you search one column, then you want to search the results of this first search action in the next searchbox. Is this possible?

Comment: I would modify the code, so it would test multiple conditions. You can use the or operator `|` to combine multiple conditions in the `filter()` function.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how to implement to test multiple conditions. All the variables are string (so not like the iris-sample set). I will give it a try.

Comment: I changed the answer to search two columns

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but I would use a dummy `data.frame` to show at startup. When you select the filters (e.g. `selectizeInput()`), the "real" data is shown.

```
 output$ex2 <- renderDT({

   myFilter <- input$myFilter

   # assuming selectizeInput() is used
   if(is.null(myFilter)){
     irisDF <- data.frame(Sepal.Length = "",
                          Sepal.Length = "",
                          Petal.Length = "",
                          theREst = "")
   } else {
     irisDF <- iris
   }

   DT::datatable(irisDF, options = list(
           dom = 'Bfrtip',
           lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')))
   )

})
```